Tables not being renamed using EF Core Fluent API
newbie to .NET and development in general,
I am trying to rename some tables in EF Core, but the changes aren't being reflected when I view the Db diagram using EF Core Power Tools.
In the code example given below, the derived join tables are named as expected (e.g. "asset_group_map"), but all tables named using the ToTable() method keep the names derived from my entities. (In this case all I would like is all lower case table names..).
This also happens (or rather, doesn't!) on non-inherited entities as well.
Using EF Core 8.
I have read through the documentation and followed a number of video tutorials but am struggling to figure it out and is probably something very simple!
Example entity:
public class Equipment : Asset
{
    public string? TagNumber { get; set; }
    public string? Make { get; set; }
    public string? Model { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}


Db Context:
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Apply configurations
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(EdiplanDbContext).Assembly);
        

        // Define TPC strategy and use a sequence to ensure continuity of Id field between tables.
        modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("AssetIds");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Asset>()
            .UseTpcMappingStrategy()
            .Property(a => a.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR [AssetIds]");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Equipment>()
            .HasBaseType<Asset>()
            .ToTable("equipment");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasBaseType<Asset>()
            .ToTable("person");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Room>()
            .HasBaseType<Asset>()
            .ToTable("room");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Asset>()
            .HasMany(a => a.AssetGroups)
            .WithMany(a => a.Assets)
            .UsingEntity("asset_group_map");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
            .HasMany(b => b.BookingGroups)
            .WithMany(b => b.Bookings)
            .UsingEntity("booking_group_map");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
            .ToTable("booking");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Production>()
            .ToTable("production");

        modelBuilder.Entity<AssetGroup>()
            .ToTable("asset_group");

        modelBuilder.Entity<BookingGroup>()
            .ToTable("booking_group");


        // Seed data here ///////////

    }

    // Extra code to update the tracking properties on the AuditableEntity
    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditableEntity>())
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.Entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entry.Entity.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}

I have tried putting the configurations inside other assemblies to see if the modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(EdiplanDbContext).Assembly) call would pick up the configuration but this doesn't work either.

Are you trying to rename existing tables? I.e. do you expect a migration to rename tables?
